# subscribing to activatedRoute, params has different attributes to hold the param value passed

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular-router

Params subscribe in targetComponent:

```
import Router from @angular/Router

  export class TargetComponent {
     constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
       this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(params => {

       console.log(params)   // receives targetName but with different attributes
       console.log(params.name);   // sometimes params has attribute name 
       console.log(params.target); // and sometimes target 

  });

  }
}
```

Sending params from firstComponent

```
import ActivatedRoute from @angular/Router

this.router.navigate(['/', 'search' , targetName]);
```

Sending params form secondcomponent

```
this.router.navigate(['/', 'table', targetName]);
```

Route Configuration

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'welcome',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'search/:name',
    component: SearchItemComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'table/:target',
    component: TableDataComponent
  }
 ]
```

Trying to understand why the params object would have 'target' attribute and sometimes 'name' to store value when navigated from different components.

Comment: How did you define the routes in your router module? I suspect for one of your routes you named it :target and the other :name

Comment: The params are just a set of key and value pairs, and the keys are the placeholder names (the :x part of the route configuration).

Comment: @narm that's right. Thought name was a defined attribute on data received

Comment: @RkRBairi, great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using something along the lines of Angular's RouterModule?

One thing I could think of is that some of the code in there is duplicated and some routes have a roundabout way of getting to their destination.

For example, you may see code looking something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'target/:name', component: TargetComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
      { path: 'target/:target', component: TargetComponent}  
]
```

The values behind the ':' are the deciding factor of what the activated routes' parameters' name are going to be (in this case either 'name' or 'target'). So, if you'd try to access target/name, but `canActivate` returns false, it goes over to target/target. Virtually, nothing changed, but the parameters' name is obviously going to be different, though the value won't be (specifically, you'd be able to access `params.target`, but not `params.name`).

**Additional Hint**

One thing to note is that the Router literally goes from top to bottom. So, given a similar scenario, if you'd switch the Array to look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'target/:target', component: TargetComponent}, 
      { path: 'target/:name', component: TargetComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]} 
]
```

The ActivatedRoutes' parameters' name would always be 'target', since there is no canActivate-Guard that could ever stop the Router from accessing that Route

Comment: yes Angular router and as you said it was merely showing the parameter names. I had given different parameter names for different routes. like Search/:name and target/:target. Now changed all to same param attribute to access.

Comment: Glad it helped!